# How to summarize an if/then/else formula in CR

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula which calculates the commission earned by a salesperson. We store our invoices under each salesperson, so it's easy to separate them. I need a way to summarize this formula, and I can't use either a running total or a summary because each customer has a different commission rate per pound sold. Currently, the formula to calculate what rate the commission should be applied something like this:

```
if {cust.custnum} = "101010" then .0250*sum(@metal lbs, {invoice.invoicenum})
else if etc.
```

where `{@metal lbs}` is a formula that has to be used as an intermediary to get the weight of the metal on the invoice, and looks like this:

```
IF {INVOICELINEDETAIL.GLCode} = "METAL " THEN
    {INVOICELINE.Wt}
ELSE
    0
```

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I'm trying to give as many pertinent details as possible.

Comment: unable to understand... can you show sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If you group by customer and then also group by invoice number then you could put your summary in the customer footer, would that work for you?

Another thought is I believe in running total you can set a formula for the evaluation so maybe you could use the nested if there and achieve what you need?

Comment: It's currently set up with the salesman as the first group, the customer as the second group, and the invoice # as the third. I've had no problems calculating the totals for each customer, but I'm having a hard time finding a way to use those customer totals in a formula, summary, or running total for each salesperson.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new summary formula for the salesman footer which contains your commission formula but modified as "sum(@metal lbs, {cust.custnum})" as that should summarise all the invoice commissions for that customer and salesperson?